# Class admin does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Having problem with Laravel 5.5. Simple website is working fine. But when I access admin panel I get this error after logging in.

> ReflectionException thrown with message "Class admin does not exist"

**app\Http\Middleware\Admin.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()){

            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function(){

    Route::post('toggledeliver/{orderId}','OrderController@toggledeliver')->name('toggle.deliver');

    Route::post('toggledeliver/{productId}','ProductsController@toggledeliver')->name('product.deliver');


    Route::get('/',function(){
        return view('admin.index');
    })->name('admin.index');
});
```

Comment: Have you registered the “admin” middleware in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`? I.e. adding ‘“admin” => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin` in the `$routeMiddleware` array?

Comment: You need to register `Admin` class ino `app/http/Kernel.php` file like: `'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',` in `protected $routeMiddleware`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After creating **middleware** you need to register it in `app/http/Kernel.php` file in `protected $routeMiddleware` **array**! Then you can use this **middleware** in your routes(**web.php**/**api.php**)

Like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
];
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks that helped

Comment: Glad i could help you! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @ArifulIslam: My pleasure! :)

Comment: in laravel 9 is  'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,